# How to create a UITableView in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I am trying to create a `UITableView` in **Swift**. I followed a tutorial, but the `table` doesn't have the values that I try putting in it in the code. Here is the code:

```
class settingsVC2: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var items: [String] = ["We", "Heart", "Swift"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you see when you run? - did you set the delegate and datasource?

Comment: I put an empty table on the view, and connected it to the outlet. All I see is the empty table. That is all of the code I have for that view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to connect the table (delegate & datasource) to the ViewController itself.

Or you can do it programmatically by adding the following lines to your `viewDidLoad()` :

```
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self
```